# Error SQL en creación de base de datos usando comandos

Tags: sql, sql-server

Estoy tratando de crear una base de datos

```
use master
go
create database Hotel_RA170665_CI180440
ON
(NAME = Hotel_RA170665_CI180440_dat,

    FILENAME = 'C:\complementario\Hotel_RA170665_CI180440dat.mdf',
    SIZE = 5,
    MAXSIZE = 20,
    FILEGROWTH = 5
    )
LOG ON
(NAME = Hotel_RA170665_CI180440_log,

    FILENAME = 'C:\complementario\Hotel_RA170665_CI180440dat.ldf',
    SIZE = 2,
    MAXSIZE = 10,
    FILEGROWTH = 2
);
go
```

Pero a la hora de crearla me dan estos dos tipos de errores

```
**Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 6
Incorrect syntax near 'ON'.**

**Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 6
Incorrect syntax near 'NAME'.**
```

Queria saber si alguien sabe porque sucede eso

Comment: agrega por favor todo el código así como el error como imagen

Comment: edita tu pregunta y solo agrega el codigo no la imagen y tu error..!!

Comment: ¿De casualidad has copiado y pegado el código? Una vez a un amigo le pasó que un guión era un caracter griego y por lo tanto le daba error

Comment: @fredyfx no he copiado y pegado yo lo he estado creando, pero por motivo alguno a la hora de ejecutarlo me tira esos errores

Comment: ¿qué versión de SQL Server estás utilizando?